# Printing using fork

Tags: c

I am unable to understand the sequence in which the output is printed...

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int index;
    for (index = 1; index < 4; index++)
    {
        printf("HI\n"); 
        fork();
    }
    printf("Unix System Programming\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

It is easy to understand that fork works 2^n times when i only print unix programming system...But when i print HI with it...I dont understand why this sequence?
    Output:

```
HI
HI
HI
HI
HI
Unix System Programming
HI
HI
Unix System Programming
Unix System Programming
Unix System Programming
Unix System Programming
Unix System Programming
Unix System Programming
Unix System Programming
```

Comment: What is it about the output that you find puzzling?

Comment: Hint: If you run it multiple times, it's likely you will see a different sequence each time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For better visibility  i have just modified the code

```
int main(void)   
    {  
        int index;  
        for (index = 1; index < 4; index++)  
        {
            printf("We are in loop with  process id=%d\n",getpid());
            if(!fork()) { //Child process
               printf("Came inside chid with process id=%d\n",getpid());
              // _exit(0);
            } else {     //Parent process
              printf("Came inside parent with process id=%d\n",getpid());
           }
        }
        printf("We are out of loop with  process id=%d\n",getpid());
        exit(0);
    }

    [OP]   
    We are in loop with  process id=2258   -----> Main Parent   
    Came inside parent with process id=2258   
    We are in loop with  process id=2258  
    Came inside child with process id=2259  
    We are in loop with  process id=2259  
    Came inside parent with process id=2258  
    We are in loop with  process id=2258  
    Came inside parent with process id=2259  
    We are in loop with  process id=2259  
    Came inside parent with process id=2258  
    We are out of loop with  process id=2258 ----> "Outer block of loop referring main Parent  Here exit(0) will rip parent process of pid 2258 "      
    Came inside parent with process id=2259     
    We are out of loop with  process id=2259   
    Came inside child with process id=2263   
    We are out of loop with  process id=2263   
    Came inside child with process id=2261   
    We are in loop with  process id=2261   
    Came inside parent with process id=2261   
    We are out of loop with  process id=2261   
    Came inside child with process id=2264   
    We are out of loop with  process id=2264   
    Came inside child with process id=2262   
    Came inside child with process id=2260   
    We are out of loop with  process id=2262   
    We are in loop with  process id=2260   
    Came inside parent with process id=2260   
    We are out of loop with  process id=2260   
    Came inside child with process id=2265   
    We are out of loop with  process id=2265
```

First we have to consider the loop which is going to be executed 3 times
each times fork will spawn 1 child and which will have one parent definitely and the execution will be completely 
dependent on scheduling could be child or could be parent.

This will become really headache to understand once you have more iteration values .

> Now let the child be cleaned

```
    int main(void)   
            {  
                int index;  
                for (index = 1; index < 4; index++)  
                {
                    printf("We are in loop with  process id=%d\n",getpid());
                    if(!fork()) { //Child process
                       printf("Came inside chid with process id=%d\n",getpid());
                       _exit(0);
                    } else {     //Parent process
                      printf("Came inside parent with process id=%d\n",getpid());
                   }
                }
                printf("We are out of loop with  process id=%d\n",getpid());
                exit(0);
            }

    We are in loop with  process id=2393
Came inside parent with process id=2393
We are in loop with  process id=2393
Came inside chid with process id=2394
Came inside parent with process id=2393
We are in loop with  process id=2393
Came inside parent with process id=2393
We are out of loop with  process id=2393
Came inside chid with process id=2396
Came inside chid with process id=2395
```

So above OP is more clear now three times parent and three  times child execution .

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee as to which order the computer chooses to schedule the processes in, one process can completely execute before another has executed a single line.

**One possible explanation of the output:**

The columns are processes, the index is in brackets

"USP" is "Unix System Programming"
"FORK" is when a process forks
"CREATE" is when a process is created

```
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8
HI (1)
FORK   CREATE
HI (2)
FORK          CREATE
       HI (2)
       FORK          CREATE
HI (3)
FORK                        CREATE
                     HI (3)
                     FORK          CREATE
USP
              HI (3)
              FORK                        CREATE
       HI (3)
       FORK                                      CREATE
       USP
              USP
                     USP
                            USP
                                   USP
                                          USP
                                                 USP
```

The above is unlikely to be the actual output, since we don't know what order the computer schedules the processes in. You could add a process id to the print statement to indicate which process any given line of output belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed view of what is happening can be obtained by also querying the PID of each process:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int index;
    for (index = 1; index < 4; index++)
    {
        printf("HI: pid %d with i=%d will now fork\n", getpid(), index);
        if (0 == fork())
        {
                printf("I am a new process with i=%d and pid=%d\n", index, getpid());
        }
    }
    printf("Unix System Programming from pid %d\n", getpid());
    exit(0);
}
```

As for the sequence of the printf()s, fact is that the new processes being spawned take a **random** time (small, almost zero, but random nonetheless) before being fully spawned, and that time is of the same order of magnitude of the time required to the parent to spawn further processes and terminate.

Therefore, you might have:

```
process 1 prints "HI" and spawns process 2
process 2 prints "HI" and...
process 1 prints "HI" and spawns process 3
                             ... spawns process 4
...process 2 terminates ("Unix programming")
...process 3 terminates ("Unix programming")
...process 4 prints "HI"
```

and next time maybe process 2 succeeds in printing HI before process 3 is spawned, and so on. If you need a deterministic sequence, you have to implement some type of process synchronization.

Comment: to print the pids without warnings you should cast: `(int) getpid()`. A good practice is to check if `fork` succeeds, else `{ perror("fork"); exit(1); }`.

Comment: Yes and no. To be portable, probably yes; but on Linux at least, `pid_t` turns out to be a signed 32-bit integer type (`__S32_TYPE`), so it can be safely autocasted; indeed, `gcc -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall`, once `stdlib.h` is included, compiles with no warnings at all. As for the `fork()` checking, I completely agree in general - *all* functions that may fail should be checked - but in this simple test case, it would have been a unnecessary complication. Still, +1 for a good point to have brought up.